# Batch - Echo ENTIRE console output to text file (essentially a log)

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, cmd

I am the creator of a [Discord](https://discordapp.com) bot, called [Mei](https://lumitedubbz.github.io/docs/index.html). Recently, I added a feature that echos all moderation and administrative commands to the console (Windows Command Prompt). I did this by using a node module called "Logger". I would like to know how to know how to make the ENTIRE command prompt output also echo to a Log.txt file on the desktop.My very simple code is `node src/index.js
pause`, which just tells NodeJS to start the bot from Index.js. Can anyone help?

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. For anyone who may be in the same situation, this is the fix:
`node src/index.js > %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Log.txt`